# Replace Function C++ vb.net

Tags: c++, string, vb.net, replace

i´m new in C++ and my first function is the replace function from vb.net.
I want to know how to make this function perfect.
Should i wrote a "function" with return value instead of void?
(Sorry about my english)

```
void ReplaceAll(std::string &source, std::string find, std::string replace) {

  if (find.length() == 0) {
    return;
  }

  int _offset = 0;

  while (true) {

    _offset = source.find(find, _offset);

    if (_offset == -1) {
      return;
    }

    source.replace(_offset, find.length(), replace);
  }
}
```

Comment: After `std::string s = "aaaa"; ReplaceAll(s, "aa", "a");`, what value should `s` have?

Comment: ...and if one calls it as `ReplaceAll(s, "a", "a");`?

Comment: This function already exists in C++. It is called ````std::regex_replace````. Very powerful. Please see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace

Comment: Thanks for the regex info !! And the bugs in my function :)